# Why laravel timestamp fields are nullables?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, timestamp

this is not a technical question.

I'm using laravel for several projects and today I had a doubt: why Laravel timestamp fields are can be null? Is there a portability reason behind this choice or it is only useful?

What is the principle that they applied on this choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of MySQL. If they weren't set nullable in some MySQL versions MySQL would put in there own values and when they are marked as nullable, MySQL won't put there own values and values from framework will be used.

Comment: Do you think it's a good thing to use defaults?

I mean: `current_timestamp` for `created_at` and `current_timestamp on update current_timestamp` for `updated_at`.

Comment: There's no point. If you use Eloquent Laravel will handle those automatically, so there is no point to use 2 solutions that can interfere each other